# Trying to extract some number from a text

Tags: python, regex

I have a text similar to this format

"weight","156.5","height","6.3","max","146"

"weight","136.3","height","5.1","max","205"
........

my goal is to extract those number in groups so weight in the first column, height in the second column, max in the third and so forth.

so far I have managed to get the number for weight using this:

weight = re.findall(r'^\D*(\d+.\d+)',text, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)

is it possible to parse a number after a specific word?

I have found similar questions but tried them and do not work and cannot think of anything else now.

Comment: This looks like a CSV file; you might be best to start by parsing it as one.

Comment: it's not in cvs format, that's what I am trying to do actually. It has multiple values like that in a row in excel and I am just trying to make a cvs file where the first collumn would be the weight the second the height and so on.

Comment: It sure *looks* like a CSV file, although maybe not with the columns arranged as you want.  But I'd still parse it as one; it'll be easier to extract the data you want & arrange it how you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one simple way to do it is to do iterations on each element of the list and use :

```
try:
    # What you want to try
except:
    # if error
```

You will get every number in the line. But, maybe you can use a library to parse your file. Your life will be easier

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't really like how the input is given. Scott is correct in his comments in that this should be parsed in a different way. But setting that aside we can try to solve the problem as it: you probably want to use a positive lookbehind in regex. In your situation, we can use it to match a certain portion of text given that a certain word occurred just before it. You can include a positive lookbehind with (?<=texthere) followed by your original regex string.

If we want to find all values for weight:

```py
import re

sample_inputs = ['"weight","156.5","height","6.3","max","146"',
                 '"weight","122.1","height","4.1","max","116"']

search_string = r"(?<=\"weight\",) *\"*(\d+.\d+)"
compiled_string = re.compile(search_string)

results = []
for sample_input in sample_inputs:
    results.append(re.findall(compiled_string, sample_input))

print(results) # >>> [['156.5'], ['122,1']]
```

Explanation of search string:

`(?<=\"weight\",)` is a positive lookbehind and will search for `"weight",` (including the quotes)

`*\"*(\d+.\d+)` will find between 0 and unlimited spaces followed by a quote (the opening quote to your number) and then match the actual number in group 1.

Comment: thank you so much for your input I accidentally tried re.findall(r'weight\D*(\d+\.\d+),text' and worked fine. I do agree that the way the data is given is messed up but that was the point of the task I was given.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using the pandas package, pandas.read_csv() in particular. Makes life easy.